# Controlling ENTER key

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can we make a form in a page doesn't submit on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> — rather. it does the same work as pressing a particular button or icon or image?

Here are the contents of my form:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" /><input type="button" value="search"            
 onclick="searchresult()" />
```

The problem is that if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the form submits and text field clears itself but the function `searchresult()` doesn't show its effect. When only pressing the button, it works well.

Comment: I would bind to the submit event of the form rather than the click event of a button. This allows the user to submit the form by pressing enter rather than requiring the user to reach over and use their mouse.

Comment: Exactly @KevinB see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10887171/144665

Comment: @iambriansreed I think that is even worse. That means the user can't tab to the submit button and press enter. I guess they could still press spacebar.

Comment: I tried that first but it did wht it is doing on pressing enter key now  so i replaced it to button and working fine on prtessing button. generally people press enter key after typing in textfield but it is not workin in mine. i want same ajax function call either a user reach to enter key or in search button. plz suggest me in detail

Comment: @KevinB Updated my answer. Enter key is ignored unless it is a button.

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" value="search"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {   // 13 is keycode for enter
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

You can also bind to `submit()` like following

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {  // instead of only `form`, 
                                // use with `id` or `class` combination
   if(e.which == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

#### Remainder

Don't forget to place you code within

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // your code
});
```

in short

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: @thecodeparadox the selector is wrong here, that event should be bound to the text input, not the button.

Comment: @cowboy: If thecodeparadox's answer helped, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    if(!$(':focus',this).is(':button'))
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

This attaches to the form itself. If it was submitted any way other that clicking the submit button it halts the submission process. For better performance narrow down the `'form'` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of disabling the enter key, you might be able to bind to the `onsubmit` event to perform any processing prior to submitting the form. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onsubmit):

> The submit event is raised when the user clicks a submit button in a form ().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

form

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        searchresult();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: see my edit, needed the `type="button"` to be `type="submit"`

Comment: thanx for your valuable suggestion